Missing a part to ignore already changed values
I am currently learning C++ on a website and they gave an example for the use of multidimensional arrays. It is shown as a small game of Battleship looking like this:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // We put "1" to indicate there is a ship.
  bool ships[4][4] = {
    { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0 }
  };

  // Keep track of how many hits the player has and how many turns they have played in these variables
  int hits = 0;
  int numberOfTurns = 0;

  // Allow the player to keep going until they have hit all four ships
  while (hits < 4) {
    int row, column;

    cout << "Selecting coordinates\n";

    // Ask the player for a row
    cout << "Choose a row number between 0 and 3: ";
    cin >> row;

    // Ask the player for a column
    cout << "Choose a column number between 0 and 3: ";
    cin >> column;

    // Check if a ship exists in those coordinates
    if (ships[row][column]) {
      // If the player hit a ship, remove it by setting the value to zero.
      ships[row][column] = 0;

      // Increase the hit counter
      hits++;

      // Tell the player that they have hit a ship and how many ships are left
      cout << "Hit! " << (4-hits) << " left.\n\n";
    } else {
      // Tell the player that they missed
      cout << "Miss\n\n";
    }

    // Count how many turns the player has taken
    numberOfTurns++;
  }

  cout << "Victory!\n";
  cout << "You won in " << numberOfTurns << " turns";
  
  return 0;
}


Now I had the idea of changing it to be a game of Minesweeper, since the logic seems the same. (except the part of showing if a bomb is nearby or not)
So far, I got it running, the only problem I stumbled upon is, that the moment a value is true, it is changed to false and can be chosen again, resulting in the code interpreting it as "there is a bomb, you lost". Any idea how to circumvent this problem or am I completely wrong here?
Just want to reference the learned info, since it is not always clear what some code blocks are used for. So far it is fun and I hope at least with this I got it kinda right
Thanks in advance!
My code so far:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// We put "1" to indicate there is a ship.
bool bombs[4][4] = {
  { 0, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
  { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
};

// Keep track of how many hits the player has and how many turns they have played in these variables
int hits = 0;
int misses = 15;
int numberOfTurns = 0;

while (hits < 1 || misses > 0 ) {
  int row, column;

  cout << "Selecting coordinates\n";

  cout << "Choose a row number between 0 and 3: ";
  cin >> row;

  cout << "Choose a column number between 0 and 3: ";
  cin >> column;

  if (bombs[row][column]) {
    // If the player hit a ship, remove it by setting the value to zero.
    bombs[row][column] = 0;
    cout << "Good Job!"<< (misses-1) << " left.\n\n" ;

    if (misses-1==0) {
        cout<< "Victory!";
        break;
    }

  }

   else {


    cout << "Ooops! You found a bomb! \n\n" ;
    break;

  }

  misses--;
  numberOfTurns++;
}


cout << "You survived " << numberOfTurns << " turns";

return 0;
}



You seem to have a mixture of the two games still in your code. If the player hits a bomb, you treat it as a miss. You should change the values in your matrix to the proper boolean  types true and false, to indicate bomb or empty space.

Unrelated to your question, but I suggest you read this. Also a sign that the site you're using may not be the best place to learn from, IMO.

This is an over-simplified version and adjudges the player to be a winner if they make 10 selections without hitting a mine:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_TRIES = 10;

int main() {
    // We put "1" to indicate there is a ship.
    bool bombs[4][4] = {
        { false, true, false, false },
        { true, false, true, false },
        { false, false, false, false },
        { false, false, true, false }
    };

    // Keep track of how many hits the player has and how many turns they have played in these variables
    int misses = 0;
    int numberOfTurns = 0;

    while (numberOfTurns < MAX_TRIES) {
        int row, column;

        cout << "Choose a row number between 0 and 3: ";
        cin >> row;

        cout << "Choose a column number between 0 and 3: ";
        cin >> column;

        if (bombs[row][column]) {
            // If the player hit a bomb, the game is over
            cout << "BOOM! you are sunk" << endl << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfTurns++;
        }
    }
    if (numberOfTurns == MAX_TRIES)
    {
    cout << "You survived the deadly mines" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

You may wish to add some code to randomly fill the matrix after each game to allow the player to try again.
